# Directory.GetDirectories on %USERPROFILE%\My Documents

Tags: vb.net, environment, system.io.directory

I'm creating a UserControl for my program which will mimic the OpenFileDialog.
When I navigate to a Directory I am using

```
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Path)
```

and

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path)
```

to obtain the contents of the Directory.

When I navigate to %USERPROFILE% (In my case it is C:\Users*UserName*) and there is a hidden My Documents folder as well as a Documents folder.

When you navigate to the My Documents folder it takes you to the Documents folder, but it appears in the list from

```
System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(Path)
```

My question is, is there a way, in code, to find where the My Documents folder is pointing to?

I know that I can find where the My Documents folder is by using

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

but I need to find the actual path each directory will save to in case it's different than it's actual address.

I'd be open to alternatives if it isn't possible.

Thanks

Comment: "My Documents" is not a real directory.  It is a symbolic link that redirects to the "Documents" directory.  It exists for appcompat reasons, keeping old programs running that were written by confused programmers that hard-coded the directory name in their code.  You need to ignore it in your code, do so by paying attention to the DirectoryInfo.Attributes.  Anything that has ReparsePoint, System and possibly Hidden turned on is something you want to ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but since some people have administrator privileges and can see this link, I need to have it showing, as it can be seen when Hidden and System files are visible.  Is there any way I can find the target of the link?

Comment: It's always nice to receive help. Thanks Andrew. That was sarcasm. Obviously I have Googled it.

Comment: @SteMoore [Reparse Points & Junctions and God knows what else using Directory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/38928c44-119b-4d5f-97ca-fda1fafbd572/reparse-points-junctions-and-god-knows-what-else-using-directory?forum=vbgeneral) leads to other pages which contain some documentation about the link target.